How to add root level static files to Quasar 2 framework?
I'm attempting to add a /robots.txt file to a quasar version 2 SPA. The problem is none of the standard Vue static file tricks seem to work here.
I have attempted to add the robots.txt file to the following folders and none seem to work.
/public/
/src/public/
/src/statics/

The first two are handled by the router, and because there is no configured route. It'll claim it can't find it.
The last one works, but you can't access it from the root level. You need to navigate to https://[domain]/statics/robots.txt.
Which of course will not work for robots.txt...
I have done a bit of searching around with no luck. I'm just wondering if someone has an answer for this? Surely you must be able to host root level static files.
I can't just add the file to the root folder manually because I'm hosting it in Cloudflare workers, and I don't believe there is an access to the hosted files system. Unlike Azure where you could use KUDU...
Thanks in advance.

It should be public/robots.txt, and that's all. "The first two are handled by the router, and because there is no configured route" - why are you sure about that? This shouldn't happen. It could be some problem with a way the app is deployed and served. The question doesn't mention this

Thanks for replying. I'm testing locally and in cloudflare. Locally I'm using npx quasar dev to run an instance, and in cloudflare it's using quasar build to build it. When I navigate to the local version I get 'Cannot GET /robots.txt' returned. If I do it in cloudflare, it's ignored, and the app will just load the home page. Quasar does do things a little differently to typical VueJs SPAs. https://quasar.dev/

Yes, I use quasar and aware of how it works. It follows the convention of other vue setups regarding how "public" works and uses the same tools (vite/webpack) to provide this. There's no such problem in general to do what you describe, it's specific to your case, please, provide it a way to reproduce, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Generally you initialize Vite or Webpack project with npm init quasar, put robots.txt to public and expect it to be available in web root both with dev and build commands. That you have a problem means that your setup differs from a trouble-free one

Okay thanks, I'll attempt to roll up a new init quasar and see if I can spot the difference. I suspect I do not have vite installed. I'll confirm thanks.

Hi @EstusFlask. I tried another vanilla project and yes it did work. In the end, I had something odd happen with the routing it seemed. After auditing the npm packages I decided to just port it to a Nuxt app and move away from Quasar 2. As there were quite a few high and critical warnings..
Thanks for your help
